# Java tool/software which has the Auto-Complete after indexing folders and files?

Tags: open-source

Intellij has auto-complete feature for just class name alone

Eclipse has auto-complete feature for just class name alone

Assume i have 5,000 books in pdf or text format.

I want them to be indexed and all the unique words should be captured.

Is there is any common software or tool with nice features which index the given folder and files and provide the auto-complete features - type ahead words like in Google search for the words exist in the entire content and with number of hits found as well?

Thanks.